# Using value from query before the query executes (PHP/MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

The following query works fine - as long as the URL focuses on one of the 50 U.S. states (e.g. MySite/World/Arizona).

```
SELECT GG.N, GG.IDArea MyID,
 GG.Name GName, GG.FIPS, GG.NameAlph, GG.Type, GG.**IDParent**, GG.Parent, GG.IDReg, GG.Pre, GG.Post,  GG.CIA, 
GP.IDArea GPIDArea, GP.IDParent2, GS.N, GS.IDArea SymArea, GS.URL, GS.PostURL, GS.Unique, GS.Title,   GS.Subtitle,   GS.MyKind2, GS.Symbol, GS.Latin, GS.Desig, GS.DesigGen, GS.DesigGroup, GS.Date, GS.Dupe,
GM.Motto, GM.Language, ART.ID, ART.PostURL, ART.Article
FROM gw_geog GG
LEFT JOIN gs GS ON GS.IDArea = GG.IDArea
LEFT JOIN gw_geog_par2 GP ON GP.IDArea = GG.IDArea
LEFT JOIN gs2_motto GM ON GM.Motto = GS.Symbol
LEFT JOIN gs_articles_world_**usa** ART ON ART.ID = GS.IDArea AND ART.PostURL = GS.PostURL
WHERE GG.Name = :MyURL AND
ORDER BY GS.N
```

However, it doesn't work with MySite/World/Japan. The problem is the database table gs_articles_world_usa. It's one of a series of tables, with the last three letters representing a nation state's parent. (Japan's parent in this case is Eurasia, abbreviated eur.)

Fortunately, these parent ID's are stored in one of the tables - gw_geog, in field IDParent. So I ought to be able to change gs_articles_word_usa to gs_articles_world_$IDParent.

The obvious problem is that the values for $IDParent - $IDParent = $row['IDParent'] - can't be pulled from the database until AFTER the query has finished executing.

The obvious solution is to make a separate query before this query designed to extract the values for $IDParent. However, I suspect there might be some way to modify my existing query to accomplish the same thing. Any suggestions?

P.S. Some of the values stored in field IDParent include usa, can (Canada), na (North America), sa (South America), eur (Eurasia), afr (Africa), jpn (Japan); pac, atl, ino (Pacific, Atlantic and Indian oceans) and reg (Regions).

CREATE TABLE `gw_geog` (
 `N` mediumint(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `IDArea` varchar(7) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `ISO2` varchar(6) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `ISON` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
 `FIPS` char(2) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `Name` varchar(44) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `NameAlph` varchar(44) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `Type` char(3) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `IDParent` char(4) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `Parent` varchar(22) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `IDParent2` char(4) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `Parent2` varchar(22) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `IDReg` varchar(7) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `Pre` varchar(44) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `Post` varchar(44) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `CIA` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `G1` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 PRIMARY KEY (`N`),
 KEY `Parent` (`Parent`),
 KEY `IDReg` (`IDReg`),
 KEY `IDArea` (`IDArea`),
 KEY `IDParent` (`IDParent`),
 KEY `Name` (`Name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=549 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci

Comment: Can you show some sample data from the tags tables?

Comment: I appended some values for the field IDParent to my first post, along with a CREATE TABLE schematic. GG.Name and GS.URL generally have the same values (e.g. New_York, France). GG.IDArea, GP.IDArea and GS.IDArea are also identical; they hold official codes for nations (e.g. jpn for Japan) and states (us-az for Arizona).

Comment: This query must be transcribed incorrectly. It cannot work as written.

Comment: @ Strawberry - I'll take that as a compliment. ;) If you're referring to the asterisks, they simply represent my attempt to make a couple elements bold. If you delete the asterisks, it works fine - as long as I'm previewing a page for a U.S. state, like MySite/World/Arizona. It's a somewhat complex project, and the table gs is particularly confusing. I'm hoping I can refine the query as I learn more about PHP and MySQL.